# Cannot find steam.exe on wine installation

Tags: wine, games, steam

I installed wine through the typical `sudo apt-get install wine`, then went to WineTricks and installed steam. Steam is working fine for me, but when I go to the folder

```
~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/
```

there is no folder `Steam`.

I want to know how things work, and this is making me uncomfortable. Where in the world is wine putting the steam.exe?

I tried running

```
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Steam/Steam.exe
```

But the result, as expected, was that wine cannot find the file. However, I installed Worms Armageddon off steam, and it put a file on my desktop with the contents

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=steam://rungameid/217200
ICONFILE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam\games\fb638fa31397002929f1466b2cfd757b7dbbb6bc.ico
ICONINDEX=0
```

So wine obviouisly has some notion of `Program Files (x86)\Steam`

---

**UPDATE**:

Also, when I run steam uninstaller, there is no listing of "steam" anywhere. However, if I ho to winetricks, click install an app, I see that steam is already checked. I cannot even uninstall it now! I even uninstalled and reinstalled wine, and still can run steam. I am **completely** lost. I don't even want to install steam anymore, I just want to UNINSTALL it.

Comment: Do you have a normal `Program Files` directory?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I do, but steam isnt there.

Comment: Did you check under `~/.wine/dosdevices/drive_c/`?

Comment: @Zacharee1 You probably mean `~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/`, and yes. I tried. Nothing there.

Comment: Oh, oops :). Look under `c:/Users/username/AppData` in either Roaming or Local.

Comment: @Zacharee1 If you mean `~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Users/username/Application Data`, that folder is completely empty.

Comment: No, there should be an AppData folder. Application Data is some sort of relic from the XP days.

Comment: My steam game data under wine is in Application Data, not AppData.

Comment: @OrganicMarble And where is your Steam.exe?

Comment: /home/[username]/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe

Comment: @OrganicMarble How in the world is it possible that it is not there for me?

Comment: I am trying to think of how that might be.  Have you tried searching for steam in nautilus?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have. Nothing came up.

Comment: Looks like you don't have steam installed. and if your are going to be playing games you should be using PlayOnLinux

Comment: Are you in the correct wine prefix?

Answer (score 1):

I think Winetricks stores its `WINEPREFIX` somewhere other than `.wine`. You would be better off using the command line and run:

```
wine ~/Downloads/SteamSetup.exe
```

That has worked for me every time before. Otherwise, you may just want to give up on Steam on Wine fully and run:

```
sudo apt install steam
```

If you do this, don't uninstall Wine just yet. There are ways to use Windows games on Linux Steam. You can use Steam Play to install the said game. Go to *Library* → *(game name)* → *Set launch options* and add this:

```
PROTON_NO_ESYNC=1 PROTON_USE_WINED3D=1 %command%
```

If you want to uninstall, I think you can just use:

```
sudo apt purge winetricks
sudo apt install winetricks
```

Hope this helps. ✓

Answer (score 0):

On my system the full path is

```
/home/[username]/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe
```

But it sounds like it can differ.  So try this.

Open a terminal and type

`wine regedit`

- Then click the + beside HKEY_CURRENT_USER
- Then click the + beside Software
- Then click the + beside Valve
- Then click on Steam

In the right hand pane look for SteamExe.  Over on the right it should show you the path to Steam.

Comment: No such path on my system.

Comment: @5xum it should be `~/.wine/dosdevices/drive_c/...`

Comment: How are you launching Steam?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Through the shortcut that was made in my Unity launcher (i.e. windows-key, write steam, hit enter)... I don't know how to see what actually happens

Comment: Is the shortcut for Steam or for the game itself?

Comment: @OrganicMarble For steam. I want to find where steam.exe is. Also the game, but first...steam.

Comment: @5xum Check modified answer.  I think this will help you find it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble There is no "Valve" under Software.

Comment: @OrganiceMarble Do you know of any way to get the "address" of the app from the quicklaunch? Because that's now the only way I can run steam...

Comment: I have no idea how your steam is working.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I found its PID, using `ps x | grep steam.exe`, and then `file /proc/2567/exe`, and the result was `broken symbolic link to '/usr/bin/wine-preloader (deleted)'`